# Ищу плагин вкладок с подгрузкой

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Все уже обыскал. Нужен скрипт вкладок (можно на jquery), чтобы в них контент подгружался из скрипта, а срабатывали они на onclick. Нашел вкладки от dynamicdrive, но там адрес для подгрузки берется из href, а через onclick не задать.

Comment: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html это не подходит?

Comment: Нет, оно не подходит, потомучто контент вкладок просто спрятан в div, а мне нужен с подгрузкой из скрипта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выдирайте из моего проекта, вот ссылка: [uniup.ru](http://uniup.ru/catalog/)